# Modify the category post counting function

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, count

I have a little problem with category post counting.
Basically, I made a custom post type, say ‘movie’, using "[custom type post UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)" plugin, and linked it with built-in category. Also, I am using the option ‘show posts count’ in category widget. So far so good.
Now, is there a way to count the number of posts except custom ones?
For example, one of my category, say ‘hobby’, has 5 normal posts + 3 custom ‘movie’ posts. Then, I want to have something like ‘hobby (5)’, not ‘hobby (8)’.
In short, I wanted to know how to counts the number of posts that does not have a post type 'movie'. If it is possible, I just want to add a function in functions.php to resolve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

p.s. – For actual example, you may want to check the following link:
http://www.mathstorehouse.com/archives/category/mathematics/discrete-math/graph-theory
In the graph-theory category, there are one normal post and one custom post. So, if I click the link, it shows a normal post only (which is what I intended). However, if you look at a category widget, it says I have two posts in the graph-theory category.

Answer (score 0):

When registering a custom taxonomy, `register_taxonomy()` accepts an `update_count_callback` argument.

This callback function will be called when the count is updated. The default callback is [`_update_post_term_count()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_update_post_term_count/) for taxonomies attached to post types, which confirms that the objects are published before counting them.

[`_update_generic_term_count()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_update_generic_term_count/) is the default for taxonomies attached to other object types, such as users.

You can check out the code for both functions to see how you can create your own callback to make the count more accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but sorry, I didn't get it. I didn't register a custom taxonomy, but I registered a custom post type and use a built-in category to categorize custom posts. So, each category can contain both normal posts and 'custom' posts. However, I want my category to count normal posts only.